# C++ maze problem, how to remove duplicates?

Tags: c++, code-duplication

I was trying to solve the well known maze problem using backtracking.
Now for each place I should try to go in 4 different directions:

> [i+1,j] [i-1,j] [i,j+1] [i,j-1]

Instead of duplicating my code 4 times to handle each direction, how can I use for loop in this case?

if I do:

```
for (int k=-1;k<2;k+=2)
{
    travel(i+k,j);
}
```

that won't cover all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved via a simple mathematics trick.

When `j` needs to be constant, `i` changes by `1` unit and when `i` needs to be constant, `j` changes by 1 unit.

Therefore, just check if the sum of the absolute values of the values to be added to `i` and `j` is equal to `1`.

```
for(int k=-1;k<2;k++){
    
    for(int l=-1;l<2;l++){
        
        if(abs(k) + abs(l) == 1){
            //cout<<k<<" "<<l<<endl;            
            travel(i+k, j+l);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array with 4 elements containing the possible combinations:

```
#include <array>   // array
#include <utility> // pair

// ...

void foo() {
    static std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 4> dir{
        {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}
    };

    // going through the 4 combinations
    for (auto[x, y] : dir) {
        travel(i + x, j + y);
    }
}
```